# Combining related data with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to build up an array of times from a set of JSON data and was hoping to do it with jq without having to write code in another language to do the processing.

The Data

```
[
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "time": 34
    },
    {
        "id": "def",
        "time": 25
    },
    {
        "id": "abc",
        "time": 45
    }
]
```

I'd like to get the output in the format of

```
{
    "abc": [ 34, 45 ],
    "def": [ 25 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $i ({}; .[$i.id] += ($i|[.time]))'
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional (`reduce`-free) approach using only jq builtins:

```
group_by(.id)
| map( {(.[0]|.id): (map([.time]) | add)} )
```